# Change item value in a list of object vb.net, doing a for-next

Tags: vb.net

Given the class...

```
Public Class Method
Public Property Sequence as integer
End class
```

and the next function

```
Public shared function SetMethod(Methods as List(of Method))
Dim i as integer

For i = 0 To (Methods.Count - 1)
    Methods(i).Sequence = i
next i

End function
```

... why is that this functions always changes all items in the list of Methods? For example, if methods.count = 10, why all methods.Sequence will have the value 10?

How can I make all items have a different value?

Comment: Depends on how the list is generated, if you add the same object to the list 10 times, then indeed all the list items (1 object reference in memory) will have Sequence 10.

Comment: Perhaps all method objects refer to the same object :p ie. 10 duplicate references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code should work as it is. But i think you have assigned always the same object to the list instead of ten different.

So something like this:

```
Dim methods as New List(Of Method)
Dim m1 As New Method()
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10 
    methods.Add(m1)
Next
```

Change it to:

```
Dim methods as New List(Of Method)
For i As Int32 = 1 To 10 
    Dim m1 As New Method()
    methods.Add(m1)
Next
```

The first approach will add the same object ten times to the list. So by modifying one you will modify all. The second approach will actually create ten different objects and is the correct way.

Side-note:

The first approach will actually add the reference to `m1` ten times to the list since all classes are reference types. It is was a value type it would create "copies". So if you'd modify class `Method` to be a `Structure` it would "work".

```
Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(methods(0),methods(1)))
```

This is never true if `Method` was a `Structure`(a value type) but always if it's the same reference as it seems to be in your case. But that's not a suggestion to use structs instead of classes. It should just show you the difference of reference- and value types.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.
The way you are creating the List may be wrong.

Try to call SetMethods using the following for reference:

```
Dim listOfMethods = New List(Of Method)()

For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    listOfMethods.Add(New Method())
Next
SetMethod(listOfMethods)
```